# What other genres or subgenres has Current Value taken on?

Tags: electronic-music

I'm a pretty big fan of a drum and bass producer known as [Current Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_Value). Easily one of my favourite artists specialising in the darker types of [drum & bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drum_and_bass).

But I've been wondering, **has he ever attempted a different subgenre other than [Neurofunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurofunk) or even a completely different genre**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, he did.

- Under his alias **Curve #146**, he released [*Curve*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Curve-146-Curve-EP/release/200940), a Techno album.
- He's also credited with his real name **Tim Eliot** in the project [Underhill with the album *Silent Siren*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Underhill-Silent-Siren/release/3486070) which involves mixed genres (rap, hip-hop).